# If $M$ is positive definite, then $\operatorname{det}{(M)}\leq \prod_i m_{ii}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

In the Wikipedia article on positive definite matrices they claim that if $M$ is positive definite, then the determinant of $M$ is bounded by the product of its diagonal entries. How might we show this?

Ideas: The sum of the diagonal entries of $M$ is the trace, which is also the sum of the eigenvalues. The product of the eigenvalues is the determinant. All the diagonal entries of $A$ must be real and strictly positive. Also we have $|m_{ij}|\leq \sqrt{m_{ii}m_{jj}}\leq \frac{m_{ii}+m_{jj}}{2}$. So far nothing is working...

We might try to write the Gram matrix $m_{ij} = \langle v_i, v_j \rangle$, and then $\prod_i m_{ii} = \prod_i \|v_i\|^2$. Now we'd need to show that the determinant, which is a polynomial in the entries of $v_i$, is less than $\prod_i \|v_i\|^2$ somehow.

Comment: This is known as [Hadamard's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $M$ is an $n\times n$ Hermitian and positive definite matrix, it has a Cholesky factorisation: there exists a nonsingular (the result is trivial if $M$ were singular, that is, positive semi-definite) triangular (pick an upper) matrix $U$ such that $M=U^*U$. Now:
$$
\det(M)=\det(U^*U)=\det(U^*)\det(U)=\overline{\det(U)}\det(U)=|\det(U)|^2.
$$
Now use the Hadamard's inequality which states that an $n\times n$ square matrix $P=[p_1,\ldots,p_n]$ ($p_i$ are the columns of $P$) satisfies $|\det(P)|\leq \prod_{i=1}^n\|p_i\|_2$. Use it on $U=[u_1,\ldots,u_n]$:
$$
|\det(U)|\leq\prod_{i=1}^n\|u_i\|_2.
$$
Now, what is the diagonal entry $m_{ii}$ of $M$? Well, it is the product $m_{ii}=u_i^*u_i=\|u_i\|_2^2$. So:
$$
\det(M)=|\det(U)|^2\leq\prod_{i=1}^n\|u_i\|_2^2=\prod_{i=1}^n m_{ii}.
$$

Comment: Thanks Pavel! I notice you answered my question about the Cholesky decomposition. Am I right that in the proof above you could have just used $M = \sqrt{M} \sqrt{M}$ rather than $M = U^* U$?

Comment: @Eric: How do you *know* $M$ has a positive square root? Effectively, you need to write $M=Q\Lambda Q^*$ where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries and then define $\sqrt M = Q\sqrt{\Lambda}Q^*$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I agree with your comment, but I'm not seeing how it's relevant to Cholesky decomposition, etc.

Comment: @Eric: I agree with your comment :) I would skip Cholesky and just use the Spectral Theorem in one fell swoop. Also, I would "bypass" Hadamard by using the geometric interpretation of $\det M$ as the signed volume of the parallelepiped determined by the column vectors.

Comment: @TedShifrin Wow, that's a beautiful geometric interpretation!

Comment: @EricAuld Yes it's right, any matrix $N$ such that $M=N^*N$ would work.