# The product of the diagonal elements less or equal the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let we have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$ - symmetric positive definite. I have to prove that $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_{ii} \le \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}(A)$, where $\lambda_i(A)$ - eigenvalue of $A$ ($\lambda_1(A) \ge \lambda_2(A) \ge ... \lambda_n(A)$).

I can prove the same for sum: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_{ii} \le \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}(A)$. Also I know how to prove Weyl inequalities $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}(A) \le \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sigma_{i}(A)$. So the similiar ways do not work for this problem.

Actually, I am not absolutely sure that my statement is true, but it seems to me that it is true.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: It works the other way: see (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/556486)

Comment: This isn't true, so either it's wrong or it's backwards.

Comment: For example, take a $2\times 2$ matrix of rank $1$ with all entries positive. The determinant is $0$ while the product of the diagonal entries is positive.