# Determinant of diag(covariance) >= determinant of covariance?

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions, covariance

I was playing with generating 2D data from a Gaussian distribution with a covariance matrix that has non-zero off-diagonal elements (i.e., a generic covariance matrix).

I noticed that, whatever covariance matrix I use for generating data, I get

$$\det(\text{diag}(\hat{\Sigma})) > \det{(\hat{\Sigma})}$$

where $\hat{\Sigma}$ is the empirical covariance matrix.

Here's a short code example in Python, in case it's helpful:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=[0, 0, 0], cov=np.array([[2, 0.9, 0.3], 
                                                                   [0.9, 4, 0.4], 
                                                                   [0.3, 0.4, 3]]), size=10000)

Σ_full = 1 / len(data) * data.T @ data
Σ_diag = Σ_full * np.eye(3)

print(np.linalg.det(Σ_diag) - np.linalg.det(Σ_full))  # <- this is positive
```

Since $\hat{\Sigma} \approx \Sigma$, on hindsight, my question is really: given a positive definite matrix, is it true that the determinant of its diagonal version is greater than or equal to the determinant of itself?

---

I'm developing an intuition of this phenomenon as follows.

We know that the determinant of $\text{diag}{(\Sigma)}$ is just the product of its diagonal entries (i.e., the variances), and the determinant of $\Sigma$ is just the determinant of its eigenvalues.
This leads to a geometric argument that, if I can argue geometrically that $\Sigma$ scales a unit space less than $\text{diag}(\Sigma)$, then the claim is obviously true.

A thought along this approach is that the column vectors of $\text{diag}{(\Sigma)}$ are orthogonal, yet those of $\Sigma$ are not. Therefore, if their column vectors were all unit length, then clearly $\Sigma$ scales a unit space less than $\text{diag}(\Sigma)$ because the column vectors of $\Sigma$ are pointing closer together (all in the positive quadrant) in space and constructs a "flatter" parallelepiped. But the problem is that their column vectors are not of unit length.

Comment: For example, for a 2-dim one, det(covariance)=var X * var Y - (cov(X,Y))^2 which is clearly <= det(diag)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556486/if-m-is-positive-definite-then-operatornamedetm-leq-prod-i-m-ii

Comment: For reference, this is related to Exercise 4.12 of Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective by Kevin Murphy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This result is known as Hadamard's inequality. First, notice that any $n\times n$ covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is positive semi-definite. If $\Sigma$ is singular, the inequality holds trivially. So, we may assume that $\Sigma$ is positive definite. Let $A=\operatorname{diag}(\Sigma)^{-1/2}$. Then $\operatorname{det}(A\Sigma A)\le 1$ iff $\operatorname{det}(\Sigma)\le \prod_{i=1}^n\Sigma_{ii}$ and, therefore, we may assume that $\Sigma_{11}=\cdots=\Sigma_{nn}=1$. Finally,
$$
\operatorname{det}(\Sigma)=\prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\le \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\right)^n=\left(\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma)\right)^n=1
$$
by the AM-GM inequality, where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Very cool. For those who are interested, Wikipedia's page on Hadamard's inequality also offer some great geometric intuition.